# How to execute a javascript command C# - selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute the following script in C# using selenium

**Script**

```
$("btn-standard buyButton currency-coins").on('click',function () {
  $(".dialog-body .ut-button-group .btn-text").click();})
```

**C# code**

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new FireFoxdriver()
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

//here I want to integrate the script
js.ExecuteScript(.....)
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()[contains(.,'Buy Now')]]")).Click(); //this button has btn-standard buyButton currency-coins class
```

How can I integrate the script?

Comment: so what is wrong with `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript` ?

Comment: You should take care, that jQuery is loaded on the page.

Comment: @Selvin, the problem is that i don't know how to set the apostrophe of the script string

Comment: I mean `string script = " here is the problem, I don't know how to convert that script in a string"`

Comment: so the question is about **escaping the double quote in C#** ? fill free to do some research

Comment: @Selvin I have tried a lot of ways but it didn't work...

Comment: tried what? backslash or double double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute javascript in Selenium C# like that :

`string commandJs = "return document.readyState";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(commandJs);`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, and I will come back with a feedback